# Core Data error iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

Hi I am using core data in my app and for some reason the first time I write to it works then subsequently I get errors.

```
- (void)addClass {

      MyClass *myclass = (MyClass *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyClass" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

      [myclass setTeacher:@"Mr B"];

      [myclass setSubject:@"Computing"];

      [myclass setRoom:@"ITB"];
      NSError *error;
      [managedObjectContext save:&error];
      [eventArray insertObject:myclass atIndex:0];
     //[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

[image: results from printout]

Comment: What errors are you receiving? I don't see any in your screenshot... that just looks like a log of an array of objects

Comment: Well you will notice in MyClassP5 has data in. This was the first entry but after that it says <fault>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the
      data: fault

tags that you are seeing?

If so, that's not actually a problem, the data is really there, it just didn't get loaded for NSLog to catch it.

right now, you have 6 actual instances of MyClass in existence, but NSLog only pulled in the specific data for the 6th one.

You can verify that it is really still there by looping through whatever NSMutableArray you are feeding to NSLog right now, and have it spit out the individual attributes on each iteration, instead of just the descriptions of each NSManaged object.

Comment: No it still says: <MyClass: 0xe08d1e0> (entity: MyClass; id: 0xe08b730 <x-coredata://0DE05636-FF81-4CC1-839E-4EB7FD830882/MyClass/p2> ; data: <fault>)

Comment: @Mike this isn't an error It says <fault> because it will not load the item until it is specificially requested. <fault> does not mean it has errored.

Comment: Yes I see now. Great help thanks. As did the link from Bot. Thanks

Comment: [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]; This is useful of course.

Answer (score 2):

`<fault>` is not an error. It doesn't load the item until specifically called. `<fault>` is just a place holder object so that it saves memory

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html